# Datatype to store dates in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sqldatatypes

Quick question that I have not be able to find a good answer to. When I started with PHP and mySQL I learned to store dates/times as Unix Timestamps. The mySQL datatype was BIGINT and PHP's date function did a great job of handling this. As I look into documentation and such it seems that the Timestamp datatype is becoming more prominent. is the BIGINT way of storing dates becoming outdated?  Is there a general school of thought over which of these methods is better to use now?

I know the timestamp datatype has 'current timestamp' for default values or on updates which is nice.

thoughts?

thanks in advance

Comment: There's also the DATE and DATETIME datatypes, I usually use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The major argument I would give is that this datatype is designed for the job.

One advantage `timestamp` has is that software understands that the number is really a date and will show a human readable date. This is always an issue when you store dates a `int`s.

One thing to keep in mind though is `timestamp` doesn't work on dates before Jan 1st 1970 but that is no different from the `int` approach.

Comment: thanks for the input. technically INTs work before 1970 if you allowed signed ints, but i rarely do that. this raises another question though. I use BIGINT so the 2038 upper limit doesn't affect me. how does/will timestamp deal with that?

Comment: From dev.mysql.com > _TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC._ -- I'll assume that when the need arises they will find a way to increase the upper bound. If you're worried about another millennium bug you can worry about it in 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, you should not use any kind of INT datatype to persist date. MySQL offers a good range of options such as TIMESTAMP (as you mentioned), DATETIME, DATE, TIME, YEAR. Also you can use the native MySQL time functions easier. So, no reason really to use any other datatype really.

[EDIT]

[MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) is quite clear about its datatypes:

```
The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’ format. The supported range is ’1000-01-01 00:00:00′ to ’9999-12-31 23:59:59′.

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of ’1970-01-01 00:00:01′ UTC to ’2038-01-19 03:14:07′ UTC.
```

Comment: like i said the timestamp type is new to me. does it work well with PHP? does it just view it as a string, or can i use the date() function to format it? also how will/do these deal with the 2038 upper limit?